# Chrome Extension window.open() does not work with <form onsubmit=xyz>

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing my first Chrome Extension and I'm fairly new to js, html and css. The problem is that whenever I use the extension it does not take the submitted value, put it into the string url by opening a new window. Please see code below for html and js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="ChromeFacebook.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="title"> Enter ID: </h1>
<h2 id="paragraphs"> Comments </h2>

 <form onsubmit="return a(this.number.value);">
 <input type="text" name="number" size="60" placeholder="Photos 
 commented"><input type="submit" value="Search">   
 </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

The code above is my ChromeFacebook.html file. Following the Concent Security Policy, I removed my inline Javascript and put the function I use in a separate file called ChromeFacebook.js (Please see code below)

```
function a(number) {
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/" + number + "/photos-
commented", "a");
};
```

When opening ChromeFacebook.html in my browser, everything works. I can't figure out why the extension doesn't like my code (or am I violating another security policy?). As mentioned at the beginning, I'm fairly new to js, html and css. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“I removed my inline Javascript”_ - and what do you think `onsubmit="return a(this.number.value);"` is …?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment! I think it's inline Javascript ;) So, I need to put it into the .js file, right?

Comment: @Lo1988, right.

Comment: @Deliaz Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: Still struggling...could anyone help me pls?